# PHP getting the cpu details and status by just using the ip address

Tags: php, laravel, server, ip, host

Is it possible to get the CPU status, the disk space, the memory usage of a host by just using their IP addresses? Is there a certain function in PHP that can do that?

Comment: Are you in control of this remote host? ie can you put a PHP script on it?

Comment: nooooooooooooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address will tell you nothing about the host on that IP address, especially since there can be multiple hosts behind that same IP.

If the host is connecting to your server via HTTP, you can check the HTTP headers to glean some information about the host, e.g. User Agent, OS, etc., but this will generally not include CPU status, disk space, or memory.

Comment: do you know how can I get it programmatically?

Comment: If your only access to a device is through its IP, there is generally no way to retrieve the information you're looking for unless you can log in to the device and query its OS. Details will depend entirely on the device's OS.